# Breaking of ODR inside one TU?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend-function, one-definition-rule

The following code [compiles without any error](https://godbolt.org/z/zcrL4_), though it seems to break ODR:

```
#include <iostream>

template<long Num>
class B;

template<long Num>
struct A {
    template<long Num1>
    friend void ffoo(A<Num1> a, B<Num>* = nullptr) {
        std::cout << "@A ffoo(A<" << Num1 << ">, B<" << Num << ">*)" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<long Num>
class B {
public:
    friend void ffoo(A<Num> a, B<Num>* = nullptr) {
        std::cout << "@B ffoo(A<" << Num << ">, B<" << Num << ">*)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    ffoo(A<1>{});         // @A ffoo(A<1>, B<1>*)
    B<1>* ptr = nullptr;
    ffoo(A<1>{}, ptr);    // @B ffoo(A<1>, B<1>*)
}
```

The [ODR Rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) allow cases for which breaking of ODR is IFNDR (*ill formed no diagnostic required*) all these cases seem to relate to programs with multiple translation units.

The [first paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#1) is quite clearly stating the requirement from a single translation unit:

> **[basic.def.odr]/1**
>
> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type,
> template, default argument for a parameter (for a function in a given
> scope), or default template argument.

**Does the above code break ODR? If it does, should breaking ODR inside a single translation unit require compiler diagnostics?**

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Note: it seems that the *friend template function* in the code example do obey to the new rules of [[temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst).</sub>

Comment: Could you explain why you think this code violates ODR?  I'm not seeing multiple definitions.

Comment: @NathanOliver there are two definitions of `ffoo(A<1>, B<1>*)` isn't it?

Comment: The friend of `B` is not a function template. Those are overloads

Comment: templates have special rules.  If a regular function is the same as a template, the regular function is chosen, no ODR violation.

Comment: You are correct that a redefinition is diagnosable. It is indeed diagnosed when you actually redefine `ffoo` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/954c266e2aae7645

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The friend of `B` is not a function template. That friend declaration is not a template declaration, so we have

> **[temp.friend]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#1) A friend of a class or class template can be a function template
> or class template, a specialization of a function template or class
> template, or a non-template function or class. **For a friend function
> declaration that is not a template declaration**:
>
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified template-id, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function
>   template, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching non-template function is found in the specified class or namespace,
>   the friend declaration refers to that function, otherwise,
> - if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend
>   declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function
>   template ([temp.deduct.decl]), otherwise,
> - **the name shall be an unqualified-id that declares (or redeclares) a non-template function**.

So the two declarations of `ffoo` don't declare the same entity. One is a function template, the other is a non-template function. These two may exist in the same declarative region as overloads.

So there is no ODR violation here.